# Set reminder task date in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

*Problem*

I have a piece of code to put the data of an excel table line by line as task in Outlook.
(Get this for MS Project Tasks in Outlook)

I am using: TaskItem object (Outlook) in VBA-Excel code
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.taskitem)

With the property: ReminderSet, I can turn the Reminder on / off.
With the property: ReminderTime, I can enter the Reminder Time.

Now I just can't find the property for *Reminderdate*.
Property: ReminderDate (or similar) is not shown in the property-list

*Question*
With which property can I fill the ReminderDate of an Outlook task?

Comment: It seems like the [`ReminderTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.taskitem.remindertime) sets both the date and time from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The `ReminderTime` property sets a Date indicating the **date and time** at which the reminder should occur for the specified item.